# Jersey 1.19 and Glassfish 3.1 error on Production linux server

Tags: java, linux, rest, jersey

I have a Rest web service with Jersey 1.19 which i deployed to Glassfish 3.1 on localhost running Windows 7, it works perfect but when trying to deploy on production running Linux, Glassfish 3.1 i'm getting **"Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. "**

Kindly advice on what i need to do to make the deployment successful on Linux server.

**Note: I get this error in the process of uploading the .WAR file to the server.**